# Selenium driver cannot be found in environment variables

Tags: c#, selenium, environment-variables

I have been using selenium and everything has been working fine.

I have been including the chromedriver and others in my bin directory so that they can be picked up.

If I move them outside this location then I get the below error message.

> Result Message:   OneTimeSetUp:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The chromedriver.exe
>   file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the
>   PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

I understand this is due to it not finding the driver exe so the location is needed to be referenced.

If i put it in the code everything works fine

```
Instance = new ChromeDriver("C:\\drivers");
```

The issue I have is that hard coded locations are bad practice and I don't want to do this as I am making a reusable component for others who may wish to store drivers on a 2nd HD.

I have added the location in to my path environment variables as the error above suggests however my code then cannot pick up the driver exe

Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: Have you added the path in User Variables or System variables in Environment Settings. Try adding in both and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the path to the web driver to your computer's PATH variable or have the path in a config file that you read from and where the path is set during installation. Oracle has a [guide](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) to adding to the PATH variable for java but if you replace java.exe with chromedriver.exe it should work out the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried all this and it didn't work, I restarted my machine and it then magically work.

I presume Selenium somehow does not manage to pick up something with the environment variables so if anyone else hits this issue try the good old turn it off and on again :)

Answer (score -1):

You are giving the path till drivers. Should you not give the path till chromedriver.exe.

i.e try replacing your code with

Instance = new ChromeDriver("C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe");

if your **chromedriver.exe** is in the folder drivers

Comment: Hi Monika, that's not the issue I am having, I can get it to work passing in the location to the driver constructor however I don't wish to do that.

Instead I am trying to have the location in the environment variables.